# fseek(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, geocoding, geo

Not sure what I have done wrong but this error has drive me mad. I keep getting "fseek(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource" error from these codes below:

```
public function _geoip_seek_country($ipnum) {
    $offset = 0;
    for ($depth = 31; $depth >= 0; $depth--) {
        if ($this->flags & $this->GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE) {
            $enc = mb_internal_encoding();
            mb_internal_encoding('ISO-8859-1');

            $buf = substr($this->memory_buffer,
                2 * $this->record_length * $offset,
                2 * $this->record_length);

            mb_internal_encoding($enc);
        } elseif ($this->flags & $this->GEOIP_SHARED_MEMORY) {
            $buf = @shmop_read ($this->shmid,
                2 * $this->record_length * $offset,
                2 * $this->record_length );
        } else {
      fseek($this->filehandle, 2 * $this->record_length * $offset, SEEK_SET) == 0
                or die("fseek failed");
            $buf = fread($this->filehandle, 2 * $this->record_length);
        }
        $x = array(0,0);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $this->record_length; ++$j) {
                $x[$i] += ord($buf[$this->record_length * $i + $j]) << ($j * 8);
            }
        }
        if ($ipnum & (1 << $depth)) {
            if ($x[1] >= $this->databaseSegments) {
                return $x[1];
            }
            $offset = $x[1];
        } else {
            if ($x[0] >= $this->databaseSegments) {
                return $x[0];
            }
            $offset = $x[0];
        }
    }
    trigger_error("error traversing database - perhaps it is corrupt?", E_USER_ERROR);
    return false;
}
```

The file does exist and set permissions as 777. The

```
$this->filehandle = fopen($filename,"rb"))
```

is already true. Not sure why it keeps saying

> Supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Comment: What does `var_dump( $this->filehandle, get_resource_type( $this->filehandle));` output if you place it right before the `fseek()` call?

Comment: It gave me NULL. I tried by explicitly put this code at the top, but still gives the same errors. 

    $this->filehandle = '/absolute-path/GeoLiteCity.dat';

Comment: `$this->filehandle` can't be a string or a filename, it needs to be a resource.

Comment: It's not clear what you meant by a "resource".

Comment: You need something like `$this->filehandle = fopen( ... );`, like you claim to do in your question.

Comment: I see. I tried to put $filename = '/absolute-path/GeoLiteCity.dat'; $this->filehandle = fopen($filename,"rb"); Now it gives another error "fread() [function.fread]: Length parameter must be greater than 0"

Comment: So what's `$this->record_length` set to? If it's `0`, you're passing `0` to `fread()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking $gi->filehandle for resource. But i think you must search problem before this code

```
if (is_resource($gi->filehandle)) {
      fseek($this->filehandle, 2 * $this->record_length * $offset, SEEK_SET) == 0 or die("fseek failed");
      $buf = fread($this->filehandle, 2 * $this->record_length);
}
```